# How to install memcache on Ubuntu Hardy?

Tags: ubuntu

How do I install and configure memcache on ubuntu hardy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[memcached](http://memcached.org/) is the [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/memcached) you want:

```
Description: A high-performance memory object caching system
 Danga Interactive developed memcached to enhance the speed of LiveJournal.com,
 a site which was already doing 20 million+ dynamic page views per day for 1
 million users with a bunch of webservers and a bunch of database servers.
 memcached dropped the database load to almost nothing, yielding faster page
 load times for users, better resource utilization, and faster access to the
 databases on a memcache miss.
 .
 memcached optimizes specific high-load serving applications that are designed
 to take advantage of its versatile no-locking memory access system. Clients
 are available in several different programming languages, to suit the needs
 of the specific application. Traditionally this has been used in mod_perl
 apps to avoid storing large chunks of data in Apache memory, and to share
 this burden across several machines.
```

### Installation

Just make sure universe is enabled and run `apt-get install memcached`.

### Configuration

In `/usr/share/doc/` are several documents you should read on memcached as deployed by Debian packaging. In particular, README.Debian:

> Memcached has two logical uses in this package, a system daemon that can be run
>   from the standard /etc/init.d/ interface, or one that can be run from userland
>   from a the command line such as
>     /usr/bin/memcached -d
>
> The former has been setup to run through the start-memcached script, reading in
>   the configuration from /etc/memcached.conf.  The start-memcached script ignores
>   certain parameters as discussed in the configuration file itself.
>
> The latter is the binary as provided by Danga, and reads in options from the
>   command line, ignoring the Debian-specific configuration file entirely.
>
> ```
>   --Jay Bonci
>   jaybonci@debian.org
> ```

Reading the postinst script, it should run by default: `update-rc.d memcached defaults >/dev/null`

Comment: Thanks for the description but I asked how to install and configure on a Hardy box.

Comment: It's in hardy? apt-get install memcached.

Comment: This no longer works as of 2012.

Comment: Care to elaborate? It's in precise...